# Text file browser

Tags: file, browser, text

I am looking for a freely available program that runs on Win7, which lets me browse through all text files in a folder. I am imagining somthing like the Windows Photo Viewer that simply displays the next image file in a folder when clicking on the [next] button, but for text files. It should open the text files regardless of their file extention.
I've got thousands of one line text files in a folder and opening them one by one isn't practical, even if I check only a a few dozen at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this methode](https://superuser.com/questions/91804/windows-7-preview-other-file-types-as-text-in-preview-pane) usignt he [PreviewConfig](http://www.softwareload.de/shop/previewconfig-utility)

Comment: Thank you! Very neat solution. PreviewConfig worked at the first try without fiddling around in the registry myself.